# Using two flags in split method in PHP. Why the | but not the &&?

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

I am trying to learn PHP and programming.
In the book I am studying there is something like:
    $flags = PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE;

$flags is used for the split() method.

The first flag is: If this flag is set, only non-empty pieces will be returned by preg_split().
The second is: If this flag is set, parenthesized expression in the delimiter pattern will be captured and returned as well.

Why isn't he using && operator but the | ?

Can you please explain what | does actually?

As far as I know these are

Comment: `|` and related operators are bitwise operators. Using bitfields you can pass an integer with certain bits turned on or off to enable or disable certain options.

Comment: The boolean `1 && 2` gives you true (`1`). While `1 | 2` is `3`, as would be `1 + 2` (which is equivalent to the bitwise OR if all operands have distinct bits set in binary notation).

Comment: So, you know that it is a bitwise operator but did not try to find out what that *means*?

Comment: @datasage So it is like passing a whole different integer? Like if PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY is 1 and PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE is 2 then when I do | for them, I am passing a different integer to the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

&& is the *logical AND* whereas | is a bitwise operator.

`a && b` evalutes to *true* when both operands are evaluted to *true*. Since flags are almost always numbers greater than 1, this expression always evalutes to *true*.

### How functions accepting bitmasks work

#### They specify constants

Note that these constants have to have powers of 2:

```
FLAG_INT1 = 1
FLAG_INT2 = 2
FLAG_INT3 = 4
FLAG_INT4 = 8
```

#### You call the function combining some flags

```
myFunction(FLAG_INT1 | FLAG_INT3)
```

This leads to a *bitwise OR operation*:

```
   0001
OR 0100
=======
   0101
```

A set bit (*1*) in one (or both) of the operands will lead to a set bit (*1*) in the result, too.

#### The function checks internally for each flag

This requires a *bitwise AND operation*:

```
    0101
AND 0001 // check for FLAG_INT1
========
    0001 // true

    0101
AND 0010 // check for FLAG_INT2
========
    0000 // false

    0101
AND 0100 // check for FLAG_INT3
========
    0100 // true
```

The *bitwise AND* required both operands to have a set bit (*1*) at position X in order to result in a set bit (*1*) in the result at position X.

Wikipedia has also a nice article about the common bitwise operators: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: Thanks, this is a great explanation, but what I do not understand is that the function gets an Integer. So when I do int1 | int2 for a int parameters, then I am neither passing int1 nor int2 but a whole different integer to the function?

Comment: @KorayTugay The *whole different integer* is not as differnt as you think, it's a combination of *int1* and *int2*. Now you might ask where the function does know about that it has been composed of *int1*  and *int2*. This is as simple as a bitwise AND operation: `if (flags & int1)` where *flags* is the given parameter.

Comment: You mean if ( int1 & int2 ) ?

Comment: @KorayTugay No, *flags & int 2* because you have to check whether *int2* is contained int *flags*. See the update, too.

Answer (score 0):

&& is the Logical "AND" 
but the | is a bitwise